# Secondary y-axis overwriting legend colors and resetting x-y tick font specification

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, plot, axis-labels

I am trying to plot 2 y-variables (primary and secondary y-axis) against one one x-variable (axis) in Matplotlib (scatterplot), with Python 2.7.

I first create 2 x-axes [twinx()]. Then I use a for loop to plot the primary y-axis scatter plot - I have to use a loop in order to iterate through the columns of a Pandas dataframe which are the x and y-variables. Then I would like to use a second for loop to add a secondary y-axis scatter plot. Finally, I would like to add a legend consisting of primary and secondary y-axis variable names.

However, when I follow these steps, I am having some problems:
s
 1. the colors of the legend symbols are not correct
 2. the colors of the symbols in the 2 scatter plots are the same so it looks like there
    is no secondary y-axis
 3. the x and y-tick labels are not picking up the correct font

Here is the code that I have:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pylab as pl
import matplotlib.cm as cm
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator, FormatStrFormatter, FuncFormatter, AutoMinorLocator
from matplotlib import cm
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib.font_manager import FontProperties

# Loading data from *.csv file:
x_var = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,5),columns=['chan','top','lk_207','robt_sh','me_sh'])
y_var = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,5),columns=['values','count','chko','54_lib','941_dat'])
y_var_sec = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,5),columns=['header_max','two','bottom_7739','max_gain','low_ext'])

# List of primary and secondary x and y-variable names:
x_var_names = x_var.columns.tolist() #primary x variable list of names
y_var_names = y_var.columns.tolist() #primary y variable list of names
y_var_sec_names = y_var_sec.columns.tolist() #secondary y variable list of names

# Matplotlib plotting begins:
fig = plt.figure(1)
fig.set_facecolor('white')
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax2=ax.twinx()

for j in range(0,len(x_var_names)): #Generate plot on primary y-axis
    ax.scatter(x_var[x_var_names[j]], y_var[y_var_names[j]], color=cm.jet(1.*j/len(x_var)), label=x_var_names[j])

ax.legend(y_var_names+y_var_sec_names, loc = 1, scatterpoints = 1)

# for label in ax2.get_xticklabels(): #NOT WOKRING
#   label.set_fontproperties(axis_tick_font)

title_font = {'fontname':'Times New Roman', 'size':'28', 'color':'black', 'weight':'bold','verticalalignment':'bottom'}
axis_font = {'fontname':'Constantia', 'size':'26'}
axis_tick_font = FontProperties(family='Times New Roman', style='normal', size=20, weight='normal', stretch='normal')
legend_fontsize = 20

ax.set_title(ax.get_title())
ax.grid(False)
ax.set_xlabel('Both X here_bottom',**axis_font)
ax.xaxis.set_label_position('bottom')
ax.set_ylabel('Primary Y here_left',**axis_font)
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(AutoMinorLocator(5))
ax.yaxis.set_minor_locator(AutoMinorLocator(5))
ax.tick_params(which='minor', length=5, width = 1)
ax.tick_params(direction='in')
ax.tick_params(which='major', width=1)
ax.tick_params(length=10)

ax2.set_ylabel('Secondary Y here_right',**axis_font)
ax2.yaxis.set_minor_locator(AutoMinorLocator(5))
ax2.tick_params(which='minor', length=5, width = 1)
ax2.tick_params(direction='in')
ax2.tick_params(which='major', width=1)
ax2.tick_params(length=10)

plt.show()
```

To dd the secondary y-axis plot, I would need to use ax2 in the `scatter()` code but I do not know how to get the colors to increment from the last primary axis color. I want the primary y-axis colors to be different from the secondary y-axis colors.

1. How can I plot the x-axis on the right (from inside the loop) and get the correct different colors from the primary y-axis?
2. How can I fix specify the font properties for the primary secondary axes' tickmarks?